# Spark SQL: Get Total Matching Rows

Tags: apache-spark-sql

I am using Spark SQL to build a query UI on top of json logs stored on Amazon S3. In the UI, most queries use limit to bring back the top results. Usually just the first ten.

Is there a way with spark sql to show the total number of rows that matched the query without re-running the query as a count?